# Liquibase scripts with PostgresQL and with H2

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, h2, liquibase

Currently my default Liquibase scripts are set without giving a dbms - this should be treated as 'is valid for all databases'.

Some scripts rely on database specific features like JSONB:

POSTGRES

```
<changeSet id="add_jsonb_field" author="me" dbms="postgresql">
        <preConditions />

        <addColumn tableName="postgresTable">
            <column name="someField" type="JSONB" />
        </addColumn>

        <rollback />
</changeSet>
```

H2

```
<changeSet id="add_text_field" author="me" dbms="h2">
        <preConditions />

        <addColumn tableName="postgresTable">
            <column name="someField" type="text" />
        </addColumn>

        <rollback />
</changeSet>
```

My assumption currently is that, with no dbms specified the script applies to any database. With dbms specified, it only applies to given database type.

So h2 should execute all general scripts and additionally the ones markes with h2.

Is my assumption correct or will h2 leave out scripts that do not carry a dbms marker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this differently to avoid having to write the `<addColumn>` twice.

In your "main" changelog (before any other changeSet), put the following property definitions:

```xml
  <property name="json_type" value="jsonb" dbms="postgresql"/>
  <property name="json_type" value="text" dbms="h2"/>
```

Then you only need a single changeset (**without** the `dbms` attribute) which uses the placeholder for the data type:

```xml
<changeSet id="add_json_column" author="me">
        <preConditions />

        <addColumn tableName="postgresTable">
            <column name="someField" type="${json_type}" />
        </addColumn>

        <rollback />
</changeSet>
```

Comment: In general I definitely agree, thank your for your concise answer. Having some legacy scripts that cannot be changed because of migration-version-control, the general assumption would still hold?

Comment: Well apparently you _are_ changing the script, so you could add the properties in the changeLog your are editing. But yes you general assumption is true

Comment: Currently I'm just trying to understand whats happening, I'm getting no error on postgres and JPA errors on H2. Thank you for your explanations!